# The checked radio button is triggered again on selection of other buttons

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

In a React project, I have certain radio buttons, of which one is checked by default. When other buttons are selected it gets triggered again. Is there any solution to avoid it? Following is the code for better calrity

```
<div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios1"
          value="option1"
          checked
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios1" checked>
          MAILING
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios2"
          value="option2"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios2">
          EMAIL
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios3"
          value="option3"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios3">
          SIMULATION
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios4"
          value="option4"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios4">
          ONO GENERIC
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios5"
          value="option5"
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios5">
          SUPRESSION ASSIGNMENT
        </label>
      </div>
```

As you can see from code above, which is taken from bootstrap framework. My intention is to make all the radio buttons work normal. Any possible solution?

Please refer to Codesandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-ritchie-jbp04g?file=/src/ProcessCampaign.js

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons doesn't work because you don't control the state of the buttons. If you remove *checked* property from the first radio button it will work as you expect. But when you set it to be checked for react it means that the internal state of that radio button never changes and since there might be only one radio button checked at the same time, you always see the first as checked.

To fixed that behavior, you have to control your radio buttons via react state.

You need to use react state to store selected radio button value and then set *checked* property to all of the radio buttons by comparing the value of each radio button to saved checked state.

Please refer to below code sample.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ProcessCamapigns = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState("option1");

  const isChecked = (value) => value === checked;

  const onSelect = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setChecked(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios1"
          value="option1"
          checked={isChecked("option1")}
          onChange={onSelect}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios1">
          MAILING
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios2"
          value="option2"
          checked={isChecked("option2")}
          onChange={onSelect}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios2">
          EMAIL
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios3"
          value="option3"
          checked={isChecked("option3")}
          onChange={onSelect}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios3">
          SIMULATION
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios4"
          value="option4"
          checked={isChecked("option4")}
          onChange={onSelect}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios4">
          ONO GENERIC
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-check">
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="exampleRadios"
          id="exampleRadios5"
          value="option5"
          checked={isChecked("option5")}
          onChange={onSelect}
        />
        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleRadios5">
          SUPRESSION ASSIGNMENT
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProcessCamapigns;
```

Also, I would recommend to dynamically create the radio buttons to eliminate duplicate code. Here is how you do it.

```
const radioButtons = [{
  id: 'exampleRadios1',
  value: 'option1',
  label: 'MAILING'
}, {
  id: 'exampleRadios2',
  value: 'option2',
  label: 'EMAIL'
}, {
  id: 'exampleRadios3',
  value: 'option3',
  label: 'SIMULATION'
}, ...];

const ProcessCamapigns = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState("option1");

  const isChecked = (value) => value === checked;

  const onSelect = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setChecked(value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      { radioButtons.map(({ id, value, label }) => {
        return (
          <div className="form-check" key={id}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="exampleRadios"
              id={id}
              value={value}
              checked={isChecked("option1")}
              onChange={onSelect}
            />
            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={id}>
             {label}
            </label>
          </div>
        )
      }) }
    </>
  );
};

export default ProcessCamapigns;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is a video where I am explaining everything in this answer - https://youtu.be/TxBwwoA8z9k  
  
Please upvote the answer if it helped you and please subscribe to my channel to watch how i answer interesting  stack overflow questions. Thank you.